# Any evidence that Garga Samhita is not authentic?

Tags: garga-samhita

An eminent Madhwist scholar says it is not authentic.

https://sites.google.com/site/madhwaprameyaqa/home/isckon-qa---hsvj

> Garga Samhita is a spurious work, very likely the creation of either Gaudiyas, or some others. None of our standard commentators mention this work. Lot of theories developed around Radha, but with not only lacking support, but going against Pramanas. The Vijayadasara Krutis mentioning Radha can also be spurious as Sri Vijayadasaru will not subscribe to the folk tales created by Sri Jayadeva. If Bhakti is diverted towards fictional characters, that is not encouraging. When the real characters Rugmini and Satyabhama are there, where is the need for finding a replacement?

Comment: Madhvas also claim that Madhvacharya is the incarnation of Vayu, Vyasatirtha is that of Prahlada, Jayatirtha is that of Sheshanaga, Lakshminarayana Tirtha is that of Dhruva & Raghavendra Tirtha to be the reincarnation of Vyasatirtha. How will the Madhvas convince these facts which appear bogus to non-Madhvas ?